# Why can Windows Run window run commands not in PATH?

Tags: windows, path

In a `cmd` window, if I type `chrome`, I get the below message because `chrome` is not in my `PATH`.

```
'chrome' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

But if in the Run window (`win + R`), I type `chrome`, chrome will run.

Why is this happening?  How does Run find the application?

Answer (score 1):

The `run` box uses all the app paths in this key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`

`command prompt` can only find things in the environmental path.

To add chrome to path, you would:

1. Open `File Explorer`, right click `This PC` and choose `Properties`.
2. On the left, click `Advanced System Settings`
3. On the `Advanced` tab, choose `Environmental Variables`.
4. Edit path under the `system variables` section add c:\program files\chrome\chrome.exe or wherever it is

Comment: Another way to start chrome from the command line would be to type `start chrome`